# Akka RestartSink doesn't restart stream

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-stream

I have a simple akka stream here and am not able to figure out why the stream never restarts correctly after killSwitches aborts the processing.  Any pointers would be much appreciated

```
object TestMain extends App {
    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("TestMain")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    val sharedKillSwitch = KillSwitches.shared("fp-change-kill-switch")

    // This stream keeps restarting after aborting and stops after 10 times 
    RestartSource.withBackoff(1 second, 1 second, 0.2, 10) {
        () => Source.tick(1 second, 1 second, 200).via(sharedKillSwitch.flow)
    }.to(Sink.foreach(println((_)))).run()

   // This does not restart at all
   Source.tick(1 second, 1 second, 400)
    .via(sharedKillSwitch.flow)
    .to(RestartSink.withBackoff[Int](1 second, 1 second, 0.2, 10) {
      () => Sink.foreach(println(_))
    }).run()

  Thread.sleep(5000)
  sharedKillSwitch.abort(new Exception(""))

}
```

What I need is to not restart the entire stream (including the source), but only restart the Sink - like in case 2 with just the RestartSink

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in RestartSink and RestartSource.

RestartSource is restarted when the flow or a sink its connected to issues an error or cancles.

RestartSink checks only canceling of the sink it manages. I think you should be able to integrate the KillSwitch flow into the sink that suppose to be recreated on restart.

Check out this [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/stream/stream-error.html#delayed-restarts-with-a-backoff-stage).